Compare the following three numbers: $a=\frac{3(2-\ln3)}{e^2},b=\frac{1}{e},c=\frac{\ln3}{3}$
How can I compare the following three numbers:  $a=\frac{3(2-\ln3)}{e^2},b=\frac{1}{e},c=\frac{\ln3}{3}$ ?
Here is my effort:
Observe $$a=\frac{\ln\frac{e^2}{3}}{\frac{e^2}{3}},b=\frac{\ln e}{e},c=\frac{\ln3}{3}$$
Consider $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$, then $a=f(\frac{e^2}{3}),b=f(e),c=f(3)$. By $f'(x)=\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}=0 \implies x=e$, we have $f(x)$ is strictly monotonically increasing on $(0,e]$, and decreasing on $[e,+\infty)$.
Since $\frac{e^2}{3}<e<3$, it follows that $f(\frac{e^2}{3})<f(e)>f(3)$, but I can't figure out how to compare $f(\frac{e^2}{3})$ and $f(3)$.
Hope your explanation will be as explicit as possible! Thank you very much!

Perhaps $\sqrt{ab}=e$ where $a=e^2/3$ and $b=3$ may help.

For $f(t)={\ln t\over t},\ t>0,$ let
$$g(x)=f(e^{1+x})- f(e^{1-x})=(1+x)e^{-1-x}-(1-x)e^{x-1}$$
Then $g(0)=0$ and $g(\log 3-1)=f(3)- f(e^2/3).$ We have
$$g'(x)=e^{-1}x(e^{x}-e^{-x})>0,\quad x>0$$
Hence the function $g$ is increasing, which implies $g(\log 3-1)>g(0)=0.$ Thus
$f(3)>f(e^2/3).$
Remark I have checked with WolframAlpha, that $f(3)-f(e^2/3)<0,0003.$

By writing $d:=1-\frac13\mathrm e$, so that $\frac13\mathrm e=1-d$, we can compare $a$ to $c$ as
$$\begin{align}\frac{a}c &= \frac{(1-d)^{-1}[1+\ln(1-d)]}{(1-d)[1-\ln(1-d)]}\\
&= \frac{\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty d^k\right)\left(1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty d^k/k\right)}{(1-d)\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty d^k/k\right)}\\
&= \frac{1-\sum_{k=2}^\infty (\mathrm H_k-1)d^k}{1-\sum_{k=2}^\infty d^k/k(k-1)},\end{align}$$
where $\mathrm H_k=\sum_{j=1}^k1/j$. Since $\mathrm H_2-1=\frac12=1/(2\cdot1)$ and $\mathrm H_k-1>1/k(k-1)$ for $k=3,4,...,$ the above ratio is less than $1$.
Similarly, the ratios $a/b$=$[1+\ln(1-d)]/(1-d)$ and $c/b=(1-d)[1-\ln(1-d)]$ may also readily (and slightly more simply) be seen as less than $1$ by series expansion in powers of $d$.
